# Add rows to a tibble dataframe so that each group has the same number of observation

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

My data is like this (it is grouped by column `group`).

```
df = data.frame(id=c('1','2','3','1','2','1'),group=c('a','a','a','b','b','c'),
                  value1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),value2=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df = group_by(df,group)
df

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
  id    group value1 value2
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1     a          1      1
2 2     a          2      2
3 3     a          3      3
4 1     b          4      4
5 2     b          5      5
6 1     c          6      6
```

Column `id` can take values among `1,2,3`. What I would like to do is for each `group`, I would like to have a row for each `id`. Right now for group `b` I only have rows for `id` 1 and 2; and for group `c` I only have 1 row for `id` 1. My ideal dataframe would look like this

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
  id    group value1 value2
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1     a          1      1
2 2     a          2      2
3 3     a          3      3
4 1     b          4      4
5 2     b          5      5
6 3     b         NA     NA
7 1     c          6      6
8 2     c         NA     NA
9 3     c         NA     NA
```

Is there any way to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete` to expand the data and then `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  complete(id, group) %>%
    arrange(group)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
#  id    group value1 value2
#  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 1     a          1      1
#2 2     a          2      2
#3 3     a          3      3
#4 1     b          4      4
#5 2     b          5      5
#6 3     b         NA     NA
#7 1     c          6      6
#8 2     c         NA     NA
#9 3     c         NA     NA
```

Comment: Hi, sorry my initial version was not accurate. I edited the question. Could you please take a look? This solution does not work when there is grouping. Thanks.

Comment: @YifanZhang your new data needs `ungroup` before the `complete.   updated